# Run docker container before run test against NestJS app using Jest

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs, nestjs

I need to test NestJS module with Jest. Original module uses 3-rd party RPC-server (NATS). Is it possible to start testing stages like so:
**npm run test** - this command will start everything that I need: RPC-server in Docker container, after that tests will be started, after passing all tests Jest will turnoff the container?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using NPM you can use the NPM hooks. The `test` command has (as default) the `pretest` and the `posttest`.

```json
{
 "pretest": "echo pretest",
 "test": "echo test",
 "posttest": "echo posttest"
}
```

You can also create your own custom script, like `custom` and NPM will run `precustom` before and `postcustom` after.

For your case, something like this may solve the problem:

```json
{
  "pretest": "sudo docker run -d -p 8000:8000 image",
  "posttest": "sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -q)",
  "test": "jest",
}
```